# Are there any window managers for Android?

Tags: multitasking

I once saw a YouTube video where someone had hooked up a bluetooth mouse and keyboard to a Galaxy Note and was manipulating apps like on a desktop computer, where each app had window decorations and multiple apps could be visible at once.

I would like to have such a window manager (preferably not requiring any external devices) for my Galaxy Nexus. There are occasionaly situations where it'd be helpful to be able to see two apps at once.

For example, I might receive complex data in an email that I want to input into another app. However, Gmail doesn't allow you to copy text from an email (which is just rediculous). So, I have to remember a little bit, switch apps, type it in, switch apps again, etc. It would be much better to be able to put my phone in landscape mode, fire up the window decorations, and tile the two apps side by side so I can see the email address at the same time I'm entering data in the other app.

I've searched for a window manager for Android, but I can't find anything, despite the video I saw. Does anyone know of one?

Comment: To copy text from an email (or most anywhere), you can long-press on it to get the copy/paste popup.  A "window manager" in Android parlance is the "launcher".

Comment: Scott probably rather refers to "floating apps" (like [AirTerm](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myboyfriendisageek.airterm) and [OverSkreen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myboyfriendisageek.airbrowser)). Or to the [Chameleon project](http://www.chameleonlauncher.com/).

Comment: @P.T.: Actually, the standard method you refer to for copying text does *not* work in the Gmail app. I've tried it many times.

Comment: @Izzy: The floating apps you refer to (AirTerm and OverSkreen) have the look I'm wanting. But I'm looking for something that will work with any apps, as I think those apps wouldn't enable me to place two different apps side by side.

Comment: What version of the Gmail app? Is the text in an image? Gmail most certainly does support copy/paste functionality as long as you're copying text (not text within an image); I just did it on my Galaxy Nexus, Gmail 4.1.2. It's a system-wide function, apps don't need to do anything special. If it's not working like that then you may have an issue of some kind to take a look at.

Comment: @ScottSeverance sorry, but AFAIK this functionality currently needs to be supported by the app itself, by using the appropriate API/Framework (see [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html), search for "floating" there).

Answer (score 1):

The window manager you saw is part of Samsung Android 4.x O.S. and only works on Samsung Tablets.

There are lots and lots of differences between Samsung Android and Google Android.

I did a quick comparison for the Galaxy S3 smartphone:
[here](http://brianshall.com/category/primary-tags/samsung)

Comment: Please don't "sign" your answers. Also, be careful about shilling your blog posts; it looks spammy.